# I want the user to ask the price of the items from the inventory_price(dictionary) so it can print the values of the keys and give it as a output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want user to choose an item from inventory_price(dictionary) and if it matches the key from dictionary it gives the value as an output.

I have tried a conditional statement to solve the problem but couldn't get anywhere.

```
inventory_price = {
    'hair_jel' : 1200,
    'hair_oil' : 500,
    'facial_kit' : 2900,
    'moisturising_cream' : 200,
    'comb' : 150 ,
    'scissors' : 300,
    'hair_color' : 450
}
price = input("What is the price of {} : ".format(inventory_price.keys()))
if price == inventory_price.keys():
    print(inventory_price.values())
```

I was expecting that it will return the value of the key in dictionary.

Comment: If you want all value items use `.values()` to get all values and if want all elements in format `(key, value)` use `.items()` method

Comment: You are missing the correct way of checking a `key` and using that `key` to find a value @DaniyalShahbaz

Answer (score 1):

- You don't check if a key is present in the dictionary by doing `price == inventory_price.keys()`, you do it by checking membership using the `in` operator by doing `if price in inventory_price` or `if price in inventory_price.keys()`, right now you are comparing a string to a list, which is not right
- You don't get the value for a key by doing `inventory_price.values()`, you do by doing `inventory_price.get(price)` or `inventory_price[price]`, right now you are printing all available values
- You can improve the formatting of `What is the price..` print statement by converting the keys to a list via `list(inventory_price.keys()))`

So the updated code will be

```
inventory_price = {'hair_jel' : 1200, 'hair_oil' : 500, 'facial_kit' :
2900, 'moisturising_cream' : 200, 'comb' : 150 , 'scissors' : 300,
'hair_color' : 450}
price = input("What is the price of {} :".format(list(inventory_price.keys())))


#If key is present in dictionary
if price in inventory_price:
    #Get the price
    print(inventory_price[price])
```

Or an optimized way is to use `dict.get` which returns the value is key is present, else returns a prdefined value, e.g. `Not Listed` in this case

```
inventory_price = {'hair_jel' : 1200, 'hair_oil' : 500, 'facial_kit' :
2900, 'moisturising_cream' : 200, 'comb' : 150 , 'scissors' : 300,
'hair_color' : 450}
price = input("What is the price of {} :".format(list(inventory_price.keys())))

#If key is present in dictionary, print the value, else print Not Listed
print(inventory_price.get(price, 'Not Listed'))
```

The output will be

```
What is the price of ['hair_jel', 'hair_oil', 'facial_kit', 'moisturising_cream', 'comb', 'scissors', 'hair_color'] :comb
150


What is the price of ['hair_jel', 'hair_oil', 'facial_kit', 'moisturising_cream', 'comb', 'scissors', 'hair_color'] :brush
Not Listed
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the line `price == inventory_price.keys()` compares if `price` is equals to keys of dictionary.

You must verify if price value contains in dictionary

Example: `if price in inventory_price`

If it is true, select the values using `dictionary[key]` selector

```
inventory_price = {'hair_jel': 1200, 'hair_oil': 500, 'facial_kit': 2900,
                   'moisturising_cream': 200, 'comb': 150, 'scissors': 300,
                   'hair_color': 450}

price = input("What is the price of {} :".format(inventory_price.keys()))
if price in inventory_price:
    print(inventory_price[price])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
inventory_price = {'hair_jel': 1200, 'hair_oil': 500, 'facial_kit':
               2900, 'moisturising_cream': 200, 'comb': 150, 'scissors': 300,
               'hair_color': 450}
price_key = input("What is the price of {}:".format(inventory_price.keys()))

default_price = "Price for '{}' Not Found".format(price_key)

price = inventory_price.get(price_key, default_price)

print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks for the help but I couldn't get the correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYJ0V.png)